# How can I go back from a JSP page to index.html (the login page) ?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm starting from here :

[image]

With that code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Login Page - please enter your Username and Password</legend>
  <form action="loginPage"> 
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration</legend>
  <form action="register"> 
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    Address   : <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    ID-number : <input type="text" name="idnumber"><br>
    User-Name : <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password  : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

And while I move from one page to another , I reach here :

[image]

With that code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Authentication failed - a problem has occurred!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sorry , but you are not registered to our bank!</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Please press here to continue</legend>
  <form action="goingBack"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Press here">
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

And I want to go back to `index.html`  - the first page that I see when the program starts (the first picture above) .

How can I do that ? how can I forward back to `index.html` ?

Regards

Comment: You want the submit button to take the user back?

Comment: @ftom2: Maybe I'd need that in the future , but for now I want to redirect to `index.html` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a link to the previous page in the last HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Authentication failed - a problem has occurred!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sorry , but you are not registered to our bank!</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Please press here to continue</legend>
  <form action="goingBack"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Press here">
  </form>
</fieldset>

 <a href="index.jsp">Go Back</a> <!-- add this -->

</body></html>
```

Comment: But why `index.jsp` and not `index.html` ?

Comment: just an example, in the href you can put whatever link you like

Answer (score 1):

You just need javascript. To redirect to `/index.html` after 5 seconds :

```
setTimeout('window.location='index.html';', 5000);
```

`setTimeout()` is a javascript function that sets a timer to trigger somehting after a given period of time. `window.location` is a variable that allows you to change the URL of the current page (thus redireting).

Comment: Where do I put that ? in a servlet or in the JSP file ?

Comment: what if he doesn't want to go back in 5 secs but on user click?

Comment: @ftom2 if it is on a button click, which is not precised here, I think the question should be deleted as it would show zero research and zero understanding of what he is doing. Basically it would be asking how to make a link..

Comment: @Jackcole This is javascript, this has to be part of the HTML page sent by your server. So here in your JSP.